# Missing non-free firmware during Debian installation

Tags: debian, wifi, firmware, iwlwifi

I'm installing the debian on my laptop for my first time and facing that problem:

> Some of your hardware needs non-free firmware files to operate. The firmware can be loaded from removable media, such as a USB stick or floppy.
> The missing firmware files are: iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode. If you have media available now, insert it, and continue.

I've tried with Debian official image writing in ISO format as well as in DD format.
I've added a necessary iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode file to the root of bootable device, but still no success, this file seems to be not visible to the installer. On debian wiki I've found

> In some cases, firmware supplied on removable media may not be detected automatically (e.g. 740503). In these situations, drop to the console (Ctrl+alt+F2) and manually mount(8) your removable storage on a temporary directory (e.g. /media).

How can I do it? Or is there any other option?

Answer (score 3):

Debian does not ship [non-free firmware](https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware) in its official distribution.

Fortunately, you can find [Unofficial non-free images including firmware packages](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/).

Use one of these images instead.

---

You specifically mention `iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode` isn't installed by your nonfree image.

I can see package `firmware-iwlwifi` version `20110315-3` in `non-free` contains this file.  If you can get a terminal while running the non-free image, use this to find the package in your installation medium and install it:

```
dpkg -i $(find / -name firmware-iwlwifi*deb)
```

---

If you can't find this package, then consider [downloading it directly](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/), putting it on a USB, mounting that USB, then `dpkg -i firmware-iwlwifi*deb` from the USB.

Comment: I've tried it also, no success. Seems like this unofficial package still does not obtain the file I'm missing

Comment: If the missing firmware is the `iwlwifi` package, then you need the firmware at an earlier point in the installation process than you have access to `dpkg` (network config happens before package-manager setup). The ISOs that ship with non-free firmware unfortunately include only `.deb` files (not the `.ucode` that the installer requires). Is there a way to extract the required files from the `.deb` **without** `dpkg`?

Comment: `apt` is configured late, but `dpkg` is always available and doesn't depend on a network.

Comment: @Stewart Ah, OK, I found it, although for some reason the binary was named `udpkg`. In the end, I needed to:
1. Go through the installer up to network config
2. Terminate network config prematurely
3. Drop to a console
4. `udpkg -i $IWLWIFIDEB`
5. Go back and re-run network config 
Is that how the ISO is intended to work? Needing to install the firmware from a `.deb` manually at a precise point in the install process seems non-intuitive, to say the least.

Comment: `iwlwifi` is a `non-free` package.  Problems like this are caused by companies who insist on hiding everything about their hardware.  Debian resists deploying closed-source binaries (hence `non-free` is not part of the official distribution) and does not put as much effort into hacking around these problems as other distros.  Instead, focus is on the open-source stuff where efforts are spent improving things instead of working around private-company-policies.  If the ease of using non-free is important to you, use another distro. Even better: don't buy closed hardware.

Comment: [It ships!](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/736065)

Comment: It does now!  Debian 12 introduced this.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've solved the issue following the instructions from
[wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi)

I've added this to **sources.list**

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
```

And then with a wired connection:

```
apt update && apt install firmware-iwlwifi
modprobe -r iwlwifi
modprobe iwlwifi
```

Answer (score 0):

Under certain conditions, you will see the message to provide drivers during installation **even when using the image including firmware**.

Some image writers will not deploy the Debian ISOs to USB media correctly. One case of this is Rufus in ISO mode (DD mode behaves correctly).

When using Rufus in ISO mode, the `firmware` folder on the resulting media will include all the expected `.deb` files with a **file size of 0 bytes**. Thus, the archives are useless during installation.

I found this issue [reported on debianforum.de](https://debianforum.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=182348) as well. If you're also running into this, re-create your installation media with a different approach.

Comment: The issue behind this is that the Debian maintainers used Rock Ridge symbolic links for a bunch of firmware files, and symbolic links are incompatible with FAT32. Symbolic links are fine for documentation or non critical files, but they should NEVER be used for firmware files or binaries that may be required for installation, because they just can't survive File System Transposition (i.e. the ability to extract content of a boot media using one file system and copy it to a different file system, which is a cornerstone of UEFI, and is what Rufus tries to use by default).

Comment: @Akeo Highly appreciated context. Thanks a lot!