# cannot install Debian non-free firmware

Tags: debian, drivers

I am trying to install Debian (the latest stable version with a netinst iso installed on a usb stick). I have got a (second) usb key containing all non free *.deb packages (downloaded from http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/). I need one of them for my realtek wifi card.

At some point, the installer asks if I want to load non-free firmware packages; I insert the (second) usb key (vfat formated), and click <yes> but nothing happens. So I move on, and click <no>. Then, the installer says:

```
No ethernet card was detected. If you know the name of the driver needed by your ethernet card, you can select it from the list.
```

Well, there is no ethernet card on my laptop, but I know the wifi card : rtw88_8822ce

on a distro live, I could retrieve this:

```
/sys/bus/pci/drivers/rtw_8822ce/0000:01:00.0
```

lsmod shows this as well:

```
rtw88_8822c           331776  1 rtw88_8822ce
```

So I select the corresponding driver on the list shown by the installer but nothing happens. So I escape this part of the installation, start a shell, and try to follow this :
[Missing non-free firmware during Debian installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/676105/missing-non-free-firmware-during-debian-installation)

```
mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
cd /mnt/debian-bulleyes.firmware/
ls | grep realt
firmware-realtek_20210315-3_all.deb
```

when entering the shell,  I cannot see any dpkg command, but udpkg

```
udpkg -i firmware-realtek_20210315-3_all.deb
```

I get an error message:

```
(process: 7331): /var/lib/dpkg/info/firmware-reltek.postint: line 7: dpkg -trigger: not found
(updating database ...)
```

then I try:

```
udpkg --unpack firmware-realtek_20210315-3_all.deb
(reading database ...)
(updating database...)
```

I retry:

```
udpkg -i firmware-realtek_20210315-3_all.deb
```

but get the same error message

then I try:

```
udpkg --configure firmware-realtek_20210315-3_all.deb
```

and get this

```
Trying to configure firmware_realtek_20210315-3_all.deb but it is not installed
```

On last thing: in /var/lib/dpkg/info/, there is a file called status; it contains something interesting:

```
[...]
Package: firmware-realtek
Status: install ok half-configured
Priority: optional
Section: non-free/kernel
Installed-Size: 2918
Maintainer: Debian Kernel Team <debian-kernel@lists.debian.org>
Version: 20210315-3
Suggests: initramfs-tools
Description: Binary firmware for Realtek wired/wifi/BT adapters
 This package contains the binary firmware for Realtek Ethernet, wifi and
 Bluetooth adapters supported by various drivers.

[...]
* Realtek 8822CE firmware (rtw88/rtw8822c_fw.bin)
* Realtek 8822C firmware (rtw88/rtw8822c_wow_fw.bin)
[...]
```

I also (desesperatly) tried (in the shell) :

```
exec firmware-realtek_20210315-3_all.deb
```

Strangely, when doing that, I get back to the installer console menu (with the marker on 'detect network hardware' !)

From there, I am stuck and dont know how to address this issue.

thanks folks!

Answer (score 0):

I installed Devuan (which is Debian on Sysv or Runit and did not stumble across such issue. I got rid of systemD at the same time.